# Which Python library should I use to allow me to pit two populations of "brains" against each other as a means of determining fitness?

Tags: python

I know practically nothing about neural networks and machine learning so bear with me.

Lets say the game we're playing is Tic-Tak-Toe (but actually more complex) where X's move first.

I am wanting to create two populations of individuals, one for the X's and one for the O's. Fitness will be determined by number of victories against individuals of the opposing population. Within each population, the fittest individuals will be more heavily weighted to move on to the next generation and the remainder of the population will be mutated versions of the individuals that make the cut.

I have tried searching the internet for a library but I don't think I have the right search terms or know enough about what I'm looking for as either all the examples and tutorials assume you are working with a data set and are trying to classify data or are over 5 years old.

Downvote this if you wish. I'm doing it for the adventure, not the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there are specific libraries out there, but it sounds like you're looking for a genetic algorithm.

This seems like a nice tutorial to guide you through the thought process for genetic algorithms: https://blog.sicara.com/getting-started-genetic-algorithms-python-tutorial-81ffa1dd72f9

If you want to visualize the X's and O's on a board, you might want to throw a GUI library into the mix, like TKinter or Kivy.

Also, this is classic:

```
"Downvote this if you wish. I'm doing it for the adventure, not the outcome."
```